# ImportError: cannot import name 'types' from partially initialized module 'telebot'

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

Полный код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Stoletnyaya_voyna_bot\botik.py", line 1, in <module>
    import telebot
  File "E:\Stoletnyaya_voyna_bot\telebot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telebot import types
ImportError: cannot import name 'types' from partially initialized module 'telebot' (most likely due to a circular import) (E:\Stoletnyaya_voyna_bot\telebot.py)
```

Код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
```

Comment: Переименуйте свой файл telebot.py на что-нибудь другое

Comment: Переименовал, не помогло.  Файл называется Bot_test

Comment: Тогда покажите новый текст ошибки с переименованным файлом

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Stoletnyaya_voyna_bot\bot_test", line 8, in <module>
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'`

Comment: Здесь другая ошибка, вроде

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/278

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Переименуйте telebot.py в что-то другое